# Dynamically change the range of a dropdown list

Tags: vba, excel

Here's what I want to do.

I have 2 cells. In one there's a list with processes and in other one with machines that do those processes... what I want to do is if I select a process in the 2nd cell the dropdown to have just the machines for that do that process.

I named the ranges with the names of the machines for each process... so what I want to do is something like:

```
If cell1.Value = X Then
    cell2 = dropdown list with the values in the range Xmachiens
End if
```

Something like that but I don't know how it's possible.
I want to load the range for that machine in the dropdown of the cell 2... Basically what I want to know is how I load a range in a cell dropdown list.

LE: I sovled the problem of adding a range to the dropdown list with:

```
With Selection.Validation
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, _
Formula1:="=$D$1:$D$3"
.IgnoreBlank = True
.InCellDropdown = True
End With
```

The problem is that if I change the value in Cell1 it will give me an error and won't change the values in the dropdown list. I guess I have to clear the dropdown list before... how can I do this?

LE: I solved the problem... I added a Selection.Validation.Delete before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sovled the problem of adding a range to the dropdown list with:

```
With Selection.Validation
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, _
Formula1:="=$D$1:$D$3"
.IgnoreBlank = True
.InCellDropdown = True
End With
```

The problem is that if I change the value in Cell1 it will give me an error and won't change the values in the dropdown list. I guess I have to clear the dropdown list before... how can I do this?

I solved the problem... I added a Selection.Validation.Delete before

Comment: Would you be interested in a NON VBA Approach?